# Inheritance Program. Where do I start?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass

Here is the project that I have been given:

> Design and implement a set of classes that define various types of electronics equipment (computers, cell phones, pagers, digital cameras, etc.). Include data values that describe various attributes of the electronics, such as the weight, cost, power usage, and name of the manufacturer. Include methods that are named appropriately for each class and that print an appropriate message. Create a driver class to instantiate and exercise several of the
>   classes.

I have done a previous one but I have no clue on where to start designing this. If I could get any tips on how to incorporate inheritance in this project it would be of great help. If I could have someone to outline the first part of the code/class to get me started, I would be perfect. Also, if you guys have any tips for future references to help me with projects of this nature. Like should I create all my classes first or finish a class one by one.

Comment: Tip 1: inheritance represents *is a* relationship. Tip 2: child inherits properties of parent

Comment: How can I apply that to this program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Design and implement a set of classes that define various types of electronics equipment (computers, cell phones, pagers, digital cameras, etc.).**

From this you know the names of your classes. If you want to use a super class and utilize similair methods among classes that would be a good idea. Maybe Technology Equipment.

**Include data values that describe various attributes of the electronics, such as the weight, cost, power usage, and name of the manufacturer.**

Here you've been given some sample instance variables that you could utilize in your superclass or sub classes. Make sure to include mutators and accessors for these attributes if in the super class.

**Include methods that are named appropriately for each class and that print an appropriate message. Create a driver class to instantiate and exercise several of the classes.**

This will just be a class with a main method to instantiate your objects from the super and subclasses

As far as an approach to answering this question I would start out by figuring out what classes I want. So think of a finite super class and then a couple sub classes. Then start to think about your attributes for the super and sub classes.

**EDIT:**

This is an EXTREMEMLY rough start. You will have to expand on something like this with more attributes mutators and accessors. And then add your subclasses.

```
public class TechnologyEquipment
{
    private double price;
    private String name;
    private String description;


    public TechnologyEquipment
    {
        this.price = 0.0;
        this.name = "";
        this.description = "";
    }


    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setDesription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public double getPrice()
    {
        return this.price;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe do some sample code for the sub class part? I am having trouble visualizing what you mean by "Technology Equipment". Like what would those methods be and look like?

Comment: Have Technology Equipment be your super class. And then have subclasses that extend it. Their header should be public class CellPhones extends TechnologyEquipment {}

Comment: I understand that part, just that what would be included in the super class? Would it just be main and println statements that show what is in the other classes?

Comment: By adding subclassses, I would then override their variables when creating another .java file?

Comment: Your subclasses will inherit all public members from the superclass. So all of the methods but not the instance variables. So when you write extends TechnologyEquipment that subclass will immediately get all of the setters and getters.